# How to create wifi network without acting like a router

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I develop some single page application, which is focused on working on some embedded device(raspberry/intel edison/etc). The networking stack on which powers on by `NetworkManager`.

The common workflow is:

1. Device starting wifi access point, and **does not** share any internet connection to it(let's say the device does not have it);
2. A user connects to this wifi access point via some phone(android/ios/whatever) and goes to the app. The web page is available on `192.168.2.20`.

But let's say, the user wants to **use a cellular connection simultaneously**(wants to view the page with my app on `192.168.2.20` and continue serf on the internet).

Is it possible to reach this using only embedded device configuration(maybe some NM config parameters)?

**What I have tried:**

- There is a [discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173894/can-i-connect-to-wifi-but-still-use-cellular) about a very similar thing, but the solution requires from user to configure static IP address while connecting to the device. I don't want to ask user about is, so, it's not acceptable.
- `systemd network` docs contains `DHCPServer` section where [EmitDNS/EmitRouter](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#EmitDNS=) option is described. But I can't find such a mechanism for NetworkManager. Moreover, I can't test if it's solving the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing I'd try is indeed to omit the default route given out via DHCP info. This is easy to configure if you directly control the DHCP server. I have no idea how to do it via Network Manager, or if it is possible at all, sorry (I avoid Network Manager if possible). You can verify your DHCP settings with `dhcpdump` if you use a second machine to connect to the AP (or install it on the embedded device). The only way to test if it's solving the problem is to check routing on the embedded device.